# PIN reset for purchases on Market

Tags: google-play-store

I created a PIN for accepting purchases on the Android Market, and I seem to have forgotten it. How can I reset it? It looks as though I can't access User Controls without said PIN. It's not a huge deal, since I can still purchase apps from the website, but it would be good to have that option if I was on the go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> Market -> Clear data`